# how to use "click" for the "lines" of a text box

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

In the following sentence I have some problem using prepositions related to `click`, `empty`.

> Please click an empty line in the textbox

From the sentence above I want to say the user to (**click/click on/click at**) an (**empty/blank**) line (**in/of**) the textbox. The alternative words are separated with an slash. Which of them are proper?

The text box is a box on a form where you can insert some data. It can have multiple lines and some lines are already filled with text, but some lines for example like the line below are blank.

I would also be thankful to receive general guides about the ambiguities I mentioned.

Comment: In order to assist you, it's important to know what the problem is and what the fix will do. User interface questions are likely better handled in other programming sites. On point, since when does a box have (blank) lines to click? But this is not a question for this site.

Comment: What's wrong with what you've written?

Comment: I rewrite the question! Please regard it

Comment: @Barmar If I knew nothing is wrong with it, I wouldn't ask here, I am not native, but I feel `click on` could be more proper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the empty line following the text in the box or can it be interstitial? If it is after the existing text, then:

"[To add text] Click (or position the cursor in case a keyboard is being used) on a blank/empty (no material difference) line following the text."

[interstitial]

"[To insert text] Click [position the cursor] on any blank/empty line.

(Uncovered is how to insert text should there be no blank lines in the existing text.)